# Untainting entries for eval in Rails 5 for badge system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently developing a badge system for a client in a Ruby on Rails 5 application. I don't want to have to hard-code every single badge into the system, and I found `eval()` as a method with dangerous consequences.

Here's my current strategy:

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User
  has_many :awards, dependent: :destroy
end
```

*app/models/badge.rb*

```
class Badge
  has_many :awards, dependent: :destroy

  # name        - string - Name of the badge
  # icon        - string - URL of badge icon
  # description - text   - Long text description of the badge
  # criterion   - text   - boolean operation to eval() to earn badge
end
```

*app/models/award.rb*

```
class Award
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :badge

  def self.automatic_award
    User.find_each do |user|
      Badge.find_each do |badge|
        # If the badge has not been awarded to the user
        if Award.where(user: user, badge: badge).blank?
          # If the badge criteria is met
          if eval(badge.criterion.untaint)
            Award.create(user: user, badge: badge)
            # Add method to notify user of award.
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end 

end
```

And I'd write a worker to run Award.automatic_award method periodically (every 10 min?) The badges would be written by Admin behind login security (not standard users) But I'm concerned about security and tainted entries.

What am I missing? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a super-dangerous practice to store code in the database and allow even an admin to maintain it. It could run literally anything on your servers and bypasses the best practices of deploying executable code, i.e. staging and testing it.

I would try to break down what the badges need to do into something you can better encapsulate as data, e.g. a rules engine or domain-specific language type framework, where you could more confidently validate the input and constrain its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you see the security issue behind this approach, but just to be clear, someone (admin or whoever has access to edit badge's criterion) can write something like `User.delete_all`. Do you trust admins that much?

I see other issues with this approach (keeping code in the DB):

- how would you test criterion code?
- there is no version control of that criterion code
- just invites errors that happen in production environment and you can't reproduce locally. How do you know the admins will write something that successfully executes?

From the example given it is difficult to guess what those criterion look like, but I would put the code where it belongs in the source of the project even if it means coding it for every single badge. I wouldn't expect the admins to know how to properly do it unless they are developers and if they are there is no reason why not to explicitly implement the criterion ins the source of the project.

In case you really need to be flexible, you better design some "relatively simple language" lets say something like: `comments > 4 && last_login > 3 days`. And allow a predefined set of "variables" `commesnts, last_login`, predefined set of predicates `<, >=, =` and so on. But something like this is not simple at all, the business value needs to justify the cost of implementation.